# ImageView Scanning Simulation Animation

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

Briefly,
Here's my **Background**.

[image]

I want to simulate scanning view, first, I'll see a RECT of

> **[** 0 **,** 0 **,** DisplayWidth **,** DisplayHight **]**

[image]

After a static period of time I'll translate smoothly to another RECT of

> **[** 0 **+ Ratio ,** 0 **+ Ratio ,** DisplayWidth **+ Ratio ,**
>   DisplayHight **+ Ratio ]**

[image]

I know I'm still have lots of logic to be added to my following code, but I'm asking about another solution with **HIGHER** performance!

```
final Bitmap Picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.world);
final ImageView Background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Background);
Display Display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point Size = new Point();
Display.getSize(Size);
final int Width = Size.x;
final int Height = Size.y;

final int[] Motion = new int[1];
final Handler Handler = new Handler();
final Runnable Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Console.Record("Running");
                Background.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(Picture, 0 + Motion[0], 0 + Motion[0], Width + Motion[0], Height + Motion[0]));
                Motion[0]++;
            }
        });
        Handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
    }
};
Runnable.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

use custom View to display moving world map? you would then avoid creating a new Bitmap for each frame of animation